# Fast way to extract data from string

Tags: java, regex, parsing, arraylist

I have a response from my OkHttpClient like:

```
{"CUSTOMER_ID":"928941293291"}
{"CUSTOMER_ID":"291389218398"}
{"CUSTOMER_ID":"1C4DC4FC-02Q9-4130-S12B-762D97FS43C"}
{"CUSTOMER_ID":"219382198"}
{"CUSTOMER_ID":"282828"}
{"CUSTOMER_ID":"21268239813"}
{"CUSTOMER_ID":"1114445184"}
{"CUSTOMER_ID":"2222222222"}
{"CUSTOMER_ID":"99218492183921"}
```

I want to extract all customerId that are of type Long (then skip 1C4DC4FC-02Q9-4130-S12B-762D97FS43C) between a minId and maxId. 
This is my implementation:

```
final List<String> customerIds = Arrays.asList(response.body().string()
                    .replace("CUSTOMER_ID", "")
                    .replace("\"", "")
                    .replace("{", "").replace(":", "")
                    .replace("}", ",").split("\\s*,\\s*"));
for (final String id : customerIds) {
    try {
        final Long idParsed = Long.valueOf(id);
        if (idParsed > minId && idParsed < maxId) {
            ids.add(idParsed);
        }
    } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
        logger.debug("NumberFormatException", e);
    }
}
```

I have a long list of customerId (around 1M) then performance are really important. This is best implementation of my behaviour?

Comment: is that somehow a json that you can parse ??

Comment: I think I see a UUID in there, do min and max even make sense here?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ my example reported is equal to my use case (only multipled for 1M rows)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I must skip that UUID and keep only CustomerId of type Long.

Comment: You code may not performance well if the number of records too big. List<String> would consume heap memory. You need the streaming approach if you can't control the length of the response. 
 
Line #3 will cause formatException as you can't convert uuid into long

Comment: @MinhKieu i can't control lenght of response :(

Comment: Then you need the streaming approach as your application will use up all heap memory and performance will be hit when JAVA is low in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a big file, then reading the content line by line can be a way to go, and dont replace the CUSTOMER_ID, but instead define a better regex pattern.

Following your approach:  replace USER_ID and use regex:

```
String x = "{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"928941293291\"}{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"291389218398\"}{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"1C4DC4FC-02Q9-4130-S12B-762D97FS43C\"}"
            + "{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"99218492183921\"}";

x = x.replaceAll("\"CUSTOMER_ID\"", "");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

or implement a regex that matches all between **:"** and **"}**

```
String x = "{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"928941293291\"}{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"291389218398\"}{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"1C4DC4FC-02Q9-4130-S12B-762D97FS43C\"}"
            + "{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"99218492183921\"}";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":\"([^\"]*)\"}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
while (m.find()) {
     System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

so no need to replace ***CUSTOMER_ID***

Comment: For 1 m record use regex !? You need 64gb ram or something like that

Comment: ohh !! I messed that part

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız what are you talking about? Using a `Pattern` and `Matcher.find()` won't require "64gb ram or something like that".

Comment: @Kayaman [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method uses regex..

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız I'm not talking about `replaceAll`, it's a bad idea to do any replacing here. The `Pattern/Matcher` won't require much memory, but it's still unnecessarily wasteful to load the full dataset in memory.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes i m talking about replaceAll. Above is not problem

Answer (score 1):

I would use a BufferedReader to read the string line by line
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

The for each line I would reduce amount of replaces

```
String id= line.replace({"CUSTOMER_ID":", "");
id = id.substring(0, id.length-2); //to avoid one more replace
```

and then apply the attempt to parse long logic, adding successfull attempts to a list.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid exceptions! When 10%-20% of your number parsing fails then it needs 10x more time to execute and it (you can write a litte test for it).

If your input is exactly like you showed it you should use cheap operations:
Read the file with a `BufferedReader` line by line (like mentioned before) or (if you have the whole data as string) us a `StringTokenizer` to handle each line separat.
Every line starts with `{"CUSTOMER_ID":"` and ends with `"}`. Don't use `replace` or regex (which is even worse) to remove this! Just use one simple `substring`:

```
String input = line.substring(16, line.length() - 2)
```

To avoid exceptions you need to find metrics to distinguish between id and a UUID(?) so your parsing works without exception. For example your ids will be positiv but your UUID contains minus signs, or a `long` can only contain 20 digits but your UUID contains 35 characters. So it's a simple if-else instead of try-catch.

For those who think its bad to not catch NumberFormatException when parsing numbers: in case there is an id which can not be parsed the whole file is corrupt which means you shouldn't try to continue but fail hard.

---

This is a little test to see the performance difference between catching exceptions and testing the input:

```
long REPEATS = 1_000_000, startTime;
final String[] inputs = new String[]{"0", "1", "42", "84", "168", "336", "672", "a-b", "1-2"};
for (int r = 0; r < 1000; r++) {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < REPEATS; i++) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(inputs[i % inputs.length]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) { /* ignore */ }
    }
    System.out.println("Try: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " ms");
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < REPEATS; i++) {
        final String input = inputs[i % inputs.length];
        if (input.indexOf('-') == -1)
            Integer.parseInt(inputs[i % inputs.length]);
    }
    System.out.println("If:  " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " ms");
}
```

My results are:

- ~20ms (testing) and ~200ms (catching) with 20% invalid input.
- ~22ms (testing) and ~130ms (catching) with 10% invalid input.

Those kinds of performance tests are easy to do right because of JIT or other optimizations. But I think you can see a direction.

Comment: Do you think that perform better to check if string contains particular char (example "-") than throw NumberFormatException to skip not valid long?

Comment: Yes! but it depends on your input. Here you expect invalid numbers and you want to abuse try-catch for control flow. I attached a little test to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore all non numeric fields

```
long[] ids = 
    Stream.of(response.body().string().split("\""))
          .mapToLong(s -> parseLong(s))
          .filter(l -> l > minId && i < maxId)
          .toArray();

static long parseLong(String s) {
    try {
        if (!s.isEmpty() && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0)))
            return Long.parseLong(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException expected) {
    }
    return Long.MIN_VALUE
}
```

Or if you are using Java 7

```
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : response.body().string().split("\"")) {
    long id = parseLong(s);
    if (id > minId && id < maxId)
        ids.add(id);
}
```

Comment: My application not using Java 8

Comment: @LuigiSaggese added how to do the same in Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Files.lines()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) to stream the data from your file. Here I demonstrate using a `stream` from a `List`.

```
List<String> sample = Arrays.asList(
        "{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"928941293291\"}",
        "{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"291389218398\"}",
        "{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"1C4DC4FC-02Q9-4130-S12B-762D97FS43C\"}",
        "{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"219382198\"}",
        "{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"282828\"}",
        "{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"21268239813\"}",
        "{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"1114445184\"}",
        "{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"2222222222\"}",
        "{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"99218492183921\"}"
);

static final long MIN_ID = 1000000L;
static final long MAX_ID = 1000000000000000000L;

public void test() {
    sample.stream()
            // Extract CustomerID
            .map(s -> s.substring("{\"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"".length(), s.length() - 2))
            // Remove any bad ones - such as UUID.
            .filter(s -> s.matches("[0-9]+"))
            // Convert to long - assumes no number too big, add a further filter for that.
            .map(s -> Long.valueOf(s))
            // Apply limits.
            .filter(l -> MIN_ID <= l && l <= MAX_ID)
            // For now - just print them.
            .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
}
```

Comment: My application not using Java 8

Answer (score 0):

First you should be trying to read the file line by line. Then from each line you should extract the id if it's matching to the pattern and collect it into an array. Here's similar solution implemented in python.

```
import re
# Open the file
with open('cids.json') as f:
    # Read line by line
    for line in f:
       try:
           # Try to extract matching id with regex pattern
           _id = re.search('^{[\w\W]+:"([A-Z\d]+-[A-Z\d]+-[A-Z\d]+-[A-Z\d]+-[A-Z\d]+)"}', line).group(1)
           customer_ids.append(_id)
       except:
           print('No match')
```